# How to give an estimation of the energy consumed by a program on an ARM platform?

Tags: arm, embedded

Is there a way to estimate the energy consumed by a program on an ARM CPU? In embedded systems, energy consumption is one of the most important parameters and I was wondering whether it is possible for a programmer to know approximately how much energy is needed to run the program?

For example, since on the ARM CPU division executed on multiple cycles I imagine that a code using divisions would consume more energy than a code that doesn't. But this reasing is quite intuitive, is there a better way to qulify the energy consumed by a CPU when executing a code?

Comment: Which platform? My arm chip doesn't even have a battery. It runs off solar panels, resorting to handwavium if solar power is unavailable.

Comment: arm makes cores not chips, despite that the only way you will know is take the specific chip and board and software and measure the power, there is no other way.

Comment: There was a paper for older ARM cores which calculated energy/instructions and a thought that compilers could optimize for it.  For most modern ARM CPUs and systems it is not a factor.  DDR and other peripherals often dwarf the CPU.  `div` and `mul` maybe implemented by a large table taking lots of silicon, but not a lot of energy.  For multi-cycle `mul`, it is calculated in long from and will take more energy.  Much depends on the transistors used in the implementation for exact energy.

Comment: People don't like your question as you need to be much more specific on the system.  For a low energy cortex-m design (maybe run on passive energy), this is an interesting question.  For most 'cell-phones' or PDA/tablets, it is not meaningful.  USB dongles, smart cards and personal fitness devices are good applications for this question.  Often other things beside the CPU will dominate though (power supply, clock, etc).  Often **peak** energy is very important as opposed to total energy.

Comment: [ISA power](http://www.ics.forth.gr/carv/greenvm/files/tr450.pdf), [ARM ins power](https://research.cs.wisc.edu/vertical/papers/2013/isa-power-struggles-tr.pdf), [ARM+compiler+algo power](http://www.teisa.unican.es/gim/pub_files/file_326.pdf), etc.  Most are book like and it is not entire clear which one would answer your question; maybe all of them.

Comment: Insert wattmeter.  Record value.  Run app, record value.  Subtract the value you first thought of.

Comment: Before you even try to do this, ask yourself what the CPU will be doing when it is not running the program.  Sleeping?  Usefully doing something else?  Reducing its clock?  If the answer is not one of these, but rather "busy waiting" (as indeed it is for the simplest first-try implementation of most embedded systems), then the question is pointless, except in calling your attention to things that are yet to be considered.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are any ARM-specific tricks here (and 'ARM' covers umpteen different things anyway).  You usually look at the current consumption in the various different power states you use (run, sleep, etc) and then estimate what proportion of time is spent in each state.  This lets you calculate average current/power.

It doesn't usually make much sense to say 'this instruction uses a lot of power' - what you might instead care about is 'this sequence of instructions take a lot of time to run, hence I can't get back to sleep quickly'.

Answer (score 1):

Closest you'll get with off the shelf tools is something similar to http://ds.arm.com/ds-5/optimize/arm-energy-probe/

Generally battery run systems have fuel gauges which are exposed through sysfs entries and can provide how much current is passing by. Think it like smart phone battery/charge indicator. Those are generally not that reliable and hard to correlate with exact time of application run, but may give you a rough estimate.